# How to generate even numbers with a length limit?

Tags: python, function

I want to generate a list of even but want to specific how many numbers to be added to the result too.

```
start, n = 2, 5

def fEven(start, n):
    #do something
fEven(start, n)
```

This should generate `2,4,6,8,10` as 5 was specified for the total number to be generated

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: you can generate even numbers with `range(startvalue, stopvalue, 2)` - you can calculate the `stopvalue = startvalue + n*2+1` then and avoid giving an odd startvalue. What did you _try_ to solve this?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct answer as all the above answers are just a workaround to print `n*2` in a loop.

What if it starts with an odd number? this handles both cases.

```
def fEven(start, n):
    res = []
    if(start%2==0):
      for i in range(n):
          res.append(start)
          start += 2
      return res
    else:
      start +=1
      for i in range(n):
          res.append(start)
          start += 2
      return res
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but it can be broken down further - don't put the for in each section of the if / else. Adjust the number first, then proceed with the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Classic loop way:

```
def fEven(start, n):
    res = []
    for i in range(n):
        res.append(start)
        start += 2
    return res
```

Or shorter:

```
def fEven(start, n):
    return [start + (i*2) for i in range(0,n)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way to solve the problem.

```
def fEven(start, n):
    return list(range(start,start + 2 * n, 2))
```